# Installing ubuntu besides windows 8

Tags: wubi, uefi, windows-8

I have been trying to install ubuntu (I tried 12.04LTS, 12.10, 12.10-secure-remix) using the wubi installer on Windows 8 and all the three times ran into the same problem showing some cannot find /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr when I tried to start ubuntu.

I tried to change the boot settings from UEFI to Legacy and then my laptop restarted and showed that "No operating System Found".

I then tried to install Ubuntu using a cd and after a lot of effort and using boot repair,etc. I landed into a new trouble. When I select UEFI on, the laptop loads Windows and windows too does not detect ubuntu. When I select Legacy mode, it starts ubuntu, shows me an option to start windows 8 but gives an error showing windows failed to load.

So in legacy mode, i am able to use only ubuntu and in UEFI mode, I am able to use only Win8. Please explain any process of starting windows in legacy mode (which I tried without any success) or starting ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: What is "12.10-secure-remix"?

Comment: It is said that 12.10-secure-remix is the UEFI mode enabled (as it is said so) version of Ubuntu. It is not officially supportes by Canonical

Comment: Ubuntu-Secure-Remix is just an Ubuntu disc with 3 pre-installed little helpful tools (especially Boot-Repair). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuSecureRemix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode, but you need it in UEFI mode as Windows is in UEFI mode.

To fix this:

1. set up your BIOS in `UEFI mode`, and disable SecureBoot /FastBoot /QuickBoot
2. boot on your Ubuntu-Secure disc (in UEFI mode if possible), choose `Try Ubuntu`, run Boot-Repair's `Recommended Repair`
3. Reboot the PC. You should see the GRUB menu with access to both Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: I got the grub menu but when it boots,ubuntu opens but windows boot fails and it is asking to insert the disk to re install

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off "**Secure Boot**" in UEFI, then install Windows 8 first, then install Ubuntu, and agree to install GRUB. It should detect both Windows 8 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Windows 8 is pre installed on the computer. Can we do something if windows is already installed and ubuntu is not installed

Comment: Just install Ubuntu on Laptop. But make sure that you turned off Secure Boot. It should work.

//EDIT: LiveCD wersion of course. If something will not work just post here.

Comment: This installed ubuntu as legacy but not i UEFI mode. Where can i change the ubuntu boot up setting as UEFI?

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 8 came pre-installed on your computer, it almost certainly boots in EFI mode. The last I heard, WUBI did *not* work with EFI-mode boots. Thus, any attempt to use WUBI with an EFI-booting Windows system is doomed to failure. You should switch tracks and do a standard (non-WUBI) Linux installation.